# regex help with word boundaries (need exception)

Tags: regex, word-boundaries

given this text:

```
hello-world
```

I can match it with this regex:

```
hello\-.+?\b
```

The catch is if I have this:

```
hello-world-howyadoing
```

that second dash is consider a word boundary, so the match ends at 'world'

How do I say 'stop at next word boundary UNLESS that word boundary is a dash' in regex?

This is in .js, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what kind of stuff you're doing, but you can probably just specify the list of word boundaries you're interested in

`hello\-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*`

Might accomplish what you want

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done JS regex's, but I'm pretty sure underscores are actually included as well in words, so the correct set would also include a `_` (I don't know if underscores need to be escaped in JS)

`hello\-[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*`

Comment: That works! Almost the same answer as Wong, but I'll have to give him the answer as he beat you to the punch. Thanks!